# Tableview update cell value after second load

Tags: swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I have two view. First view has list of folder name and search button. (tableview), second view user can search files in my server and can download it. Second tableview has file name, progress bar and download button.

When user click search button in first view then search file name and click download button, download button progress start. This process is working and I can see the progress value changes.

But when user back to first view then open second view and starts download process, I can not change the progress bar value.

I can see my codes work and tries to update tableview row but it is not. (I can see my code calls cellForRowAt indexPath method)

What is problem in my code? 
Why I can not update value in tableview row?

My update codes:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)
tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

I am updating model first than call reload tableview row. Codes:

```
dataArray[cellNum].progressValue = taskProgress
```

//Tableview cellforRowAt:

```
let identifier = "Cell"
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! SearchListCell

cell.circularProgress.angle = dataArray[indexPath.row].progressValue
cell.titleLabel.text = dataArray[indexPath.row].title

return cell
```

Also I tried update row with:

```
let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! SearchListCell!
let progressInfo = self.dataArray[indexPath.row]
cell?.circularProgress.angle = progressInfo.progressValue
```

Comment: Add your code work and UI images .

Answer (score 0):

How do you handle your progress bar value?

You can do a variable that contains the bar value, then in cellForRowAt, you set your cell progress bar value to that variable. If you already did this, please show us more code. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lucas. I have array model and there is a progres value in it. When user starts download process, I am changing progress value and refres tableview related row. I am getting progress value and change it in model via delegate. I can see the correct data in model when I refresh tableview row. Everything looks good but I can not see data in tableview. (Open first time it works and when I come back to previous page and open download page again data not changing. (download process is working and downloaded. Alos model data is correct))

Comment: Show us your cellForRowAt please.

Comment: Maybe its something bad with the circularProgress.angle. You can set a breakpoint on that line and check the value of cell.circularProgress.angle before set the data from dataArray, then go one step ahead and check the value after setting the data. If its the same, you maybe need to redo the ciruclarProgress angle and init it with your current value, else i dont know lol